# Zip code/addresses repository

Tags: repository, metadata, street-address, zipcode, country-codes

Where can I find a zipcode/addresses or country repository ? I need it in order to make some comparisons with my existing data. Is there any free or do you have any opinion how to achieve that ?

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

There is a great service that has tons of free data.  You can find it here:

Link to GEO information based on Postal Code Data
http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

Parent Link:
http://download.geonames.org/